# Forcing odata format to second API Endpoint

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

**Question : How can I force odata decoration to a standard .net core5 WebAPI endpoint?**

Details:
I already have one controller which I want to add a new Get() EndPoint.
No, I dont want to create a new controller (I already have a tons of controller for that matter).

The FIRST endpoint is a REAL odata endpoint, with oData decoration/encapsulation :
So when I do a GET() from Postman, I have this :

```
{ "@odata.context":"ablba",
  "values":[{object},{object},{object}],
  "nextlink":...
   "count":3
}
```

And in the controller :

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery()]
public IQueryable<MyModel> Get()
{
   return _Dbcontext.MyModels;
}
```

Odata will allows filtering and all that just like that and also the OdataDecoration.  In order to have full oData endpoint, it seems I am forced to add the entity / controller binding in startup.cs :

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{ 
   var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
   builder.EntitySet<MyModel>("NameOfMycontrollers");
   return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

The PROBLEM, is that I want to add a second endpoint in THE SAME CONTROLLER.  So I create my method, marked with [HttpGet] and  [Enablequery]. The new endpoint will Works with $select, $filter, etc..  but WONT RETURN IN ODATA decorations.

So it returns like this :

```
[{object},{object},{object}]
```

The problem is that I now have two 'flavor' of API endpoint, and the second one is less flexible (no paging, no count).

I tried adding a second endpoint in odataconventionmodelbuilder, but i will not work.

Also, I would really appreciate getting RID of OdataConventionModelBuilder, but article here

[using webapi odata without using ODataConventionModelBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385707/using-webapi-odata-without-using-odataconventionmodelbuilder) (not that popular), seems to point in another direction.

Soooo, that's it

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have multiple OData routes, without using the `[EnableQuery]` attribute, but it's a bit complex.

First, you need to register your route:

```cs
internal static IServiceCollection AddCustomizedODataRoute(this IServiceCollection services, string routeName, Func<IEdmModel> GetEdmModel)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddOData(opts =>
        {
            opts.AddRouteComponents(routeName, GetEdmModel(), builder =>
            {
                // customize builder, e.g. custom URI resolver
                // builder.AddSingleton<ODataUriResolver, CustomODataUriResolver>();
            });

            // odata operations allowed on the route
            opts.Filter();
            opts.OrderBy();
        });

    return services;
}
```

where `GetEdmModel` builds your model. It can be as granular as you need, and is created for that particular route only; other routes will have their own models.

```cs
services.AddCustomizedODataRoute("route1", () => 
{
    // OData ignores all NotMapped property, so we need to add them manually
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<MyEntity>(nameof(MyEntity));
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
});
```

Then, you need a way to apply the OData query based on the HTTP Query:

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyODataQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string oDataRouteName, HttpContext httpContext)
{
    if (httpContext == null)
        return source;

    // oDataRouteName should match the name used during registration
    httpContext.ODataFeature().RoutePrefix = oDataRouteName;

    var container = httpContext.Request.CreateRouteServices(oDataRouteName);
    var model = (IEdmModel)container.GetService(typeof(IEdmModel));

    var queryContext = new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(T), null);
    var queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryContext, httpContext.Request);

    return queryOptions
        .ApplyTo(source, new ODataQuerySettings
        {
            HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.True
        })
        .Cast<T>();
}
```

Finally, in your controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public MyResponseType Get()
{
  // note that this gives you more flexibility on the return type
  var models = _Dbcontext.MyEntitys.ApplyODataQuery("route1", HttpContext);

  // do whatever
  return new MyResponseType();
}
```